# Referencing another another contract returns an empty value

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I've created a consortium based network where I have two contracts deployed.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract ScoreStore{
    mapping(string => int) PersonScores;

    function AddPersonScore(string name, int startingScore){
        if(PersonScores[name]>0){
            throw;
        } else {
            PersonScores[name] = startingScore;
        }
    }

    function GetScore(string name) returns (int){
        return PersonScores[name];
    }
}
```

This contract works no problem when interacting with it directly. The second contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract IScoreStore{
    function GetScore(string name) returns (int);
}

contract MyGame{
    function ShowScore(string name) returns (int)
    {
        IScoreStore scoreStore = IScoreStore(0xEB058f7E140991811ff815335DA5bB7e593c8359);
        return scoreStore.GetScore(name);
    }
}
```

When I make a call to the MyGame contract to ShowScore("Oliver") it returns

```
{ [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }
```

When I call GetScore("Oliver") through the ScoreStore contract I get the expected result

```
{ [String: '15'] s: 1, e: 1, c: [ 15 ] }
```

What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected in Remix. The only possibility is that you wrote the wrong address when instantiating the `MyGame`.

However, your code needs improvement, many warnings appear. I did a bit of housekeeping:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract ScoreStore{
    mapping(string => uint) PersonScores;

    function AddPersonScore(string name, uint startingScore) public {
        require(PersonScores[name]>0);
        PersonScores[name] = startingScore;
    }

    function GetScore(string name) public view returns (uint){
        return PersonScores[name];
    }
}
```

And for the second:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract IScoreStore{
    function GetScore(string name) public view returns (int);
}

contract MyGame{
    function ShowScore(string name) public view returns (int) {
        IScoreStore scoreStore = IScoreStore(0xEB058f7E140991811ff815335DA5bB7e593c8359);
        return scoreStore.GetScore(name);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmmm the address being wrong is what I am thinking what the problem is however I would have assumed it would have thrown an exception when I call MyGame.ShowScore("Oliver") as the ref would be invalid no?

I'm going to make your changes and play around with it some more.

Comment: Yes the only possible problem is the address I run this and it works without changing anything in your code except the address, because it change when I deploy. On the other side I think removing warnings is healthy because this could lead to unexpected behaviors. If this answer your question please accept the answer.

Comment: Totally. I think there is/was something wrong with my network deployment. The original ScoreStore contract was no longer function correctly. There appears to be a deeper seeded issue. At least I have validation that it's not the contracts themselves. Thanks for the help.